# Change Swagger generated class names

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger, swagger-codegen

i'm generating java classes from a swagger file and following is the part of the swagger files.

```
"jobCardStepList": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "jobCardStep": {
              "type": "array",
```

for the above part Swagger is generating a java class

`UpdateJobCardRequestJobCardStepListJobCardStep.java`

I want to rename this class with a proper name.
is there any way to change the class names from the Swagger generator.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you're defining the model inline.

I would recommend defining the model in a different section and reference it in your spec. Here is an example:

Model definition: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L654

Reference: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L49

That way, the name of the Java class name will be based on the model name defined in the specification.

Comment: Is there any other way? I have the Open APi defined automatically by the server and I can't have components in other places than inline..